# Called a single key and got two values back

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I'm trying to call one value from one key but for some reason I get two values. My dictionary has a lists for it's values.

For example:

```
dict = {'HHH': ['HHH', '1', '2', '3', '4'], 'HHH2': ['HHH2', '1', '2', '3'], ...}
```

When I call the key. I get this:

```
print(dict['HHH'])
OUTPUT: ['HHH', '1', '2', '3', '4', 'HHH2', '1', '2', '3']
```

I want:

```
OUTPUT: ['HHH', '1', '2', '3', '4']
```

How do I get this?

Comment: `>>> dict = {'HHH': ['HHH', '1', '2', '3', '4'], 'HHH2': ['HHH2', '1', '2', '3']}
>>> dict
{'HHH': ['HHH', '1', '2', '3', '4'], 'HHH2': ['HHH2', '1', '2', '3']}
>>> dict['HHH']
['HHH', '1', '2', '3', '4']
>>> ` How are you getting wrong results ? What you are expecting is not even in the dict you have defined!

Comment: I forgot the '4' I added it. Sorry about that. @triple.s

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that this is an issue with how you're building the dictionary, not with how you're indexing it.

If you're not actually using a literal like you've shown, but rather adding an initially empty dictionary with both keys, and then appending the values, you might end up with those results if both keys referred to the same dictionary.

Compare what you're actually doing to this example:

```
dct = {}  # it's a bad idea to use names of builtins like dict as variables
lst = []
dct['HHH'] = lst
dct['HHH2'] = lst  # this makes the dict have two references to the same list
dct['HHH'].extend(['HHH', 1, 2, 3, 4])
print(dct)  #  prints {'HHH': ['HHH', 1, 2, 3, 4]}
dct['HHH2'].extend(['HHH2', 1, 2, 3])  # this mutates the same list as the previous extend()
print(dct)  #  prints {'HHH': ['HHH', 1, 2, 3, 4, 'HHH2', 1, 2, 3], 'HHH2': [same list]}
```

To avoid this situation, you need to make sure the lists you add to the dictionary are independent objects, not all references to the same list. In my example code, for instance, you could make it work with `dct['HHH'] = []` rather than using the `lst` variable.